# Is it possible to add a new field to an existing field of RECORD type in bigquery from UI?

Tags: google-bigquery

Is it possible to add a new field to an existing field of RECORD type in bigquery? So for example if my current schema is :

```
{u'fields': [{u'mode': u'NULLABLE', u'name': u'test1', u'type': u'STRING'},
             {u'fields': [{u'mode': u'NULLABLE',
                           u'name': u'field1',
                           u'type': u'STRING'}],
              u'mode': u'NULLABLE',
              u'name': u'recordtest',
              u'type': u'RECORD'}]}
```

Can I change it to add field "field2" to recordtest? So the new schema will look like:

```
{u'fields': [{u'mode': u'NULLABLE', u'name': u'test1', u'type': u'STRING'},
             {u'fields': [{u'mode': u'NULLABLE',
                           u'name': u'field1',
                           u'type': u'STRING'},
                          {u'mode': u'NULLABLE',
                           u'name': u'field2',
                           u'type': u'STRING'}],
              u'mode': u'NULLABLE',
              u'name': u'recordtest',
              u'type': u'RECORD'}]}
```

I couldn't find a way to do this from the UI. But I was able to do this using the API.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

This can be done totally from within UI using respective API Explorers

First, you need to get schema of your table. You can do this using [Tables.get API Explorer](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/tables/get#try-it). Make sure you select/check schema in `fields` box (better to leave the rest unchecked). Click `Authorize and Execute`. When done - Copy response text - it will look somehow like below

```
{
 "schema": {
  "fields": [
   {
    "name": "id",
    "type": "STRING",
    "mode": "NULLABLE"
   },

... 

   {
    "name": "comment",
    "type": "STRING",
    "mode": "NULLABLE"
   }
  ]
 }
}
```

Then, use [Tables.patch API Explorer](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/tables/patch#try-it)
Add needed fields(s) into previously retrieved schema and paste it as is into `Patch Body` box (chose freeform editor in the right-top corner of this box and just replace whatever inside with your schema's text). Again click `Authorize and Execute`

You done now.
Note that no matter where you put your new field within record  - it will be added to the end of this record fields

Btw, alternatively, you can use standalone Explorers
[Services > BigQuery API v2](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/bigquery/v2/)

The ones that we used here are `bigquery.jobs.get` and `bigquery.tables.patch`

Comment: Thanks! I totally forgot about the explorer. Is there any way to do it from the https://bigquery.cloud.google.com/ UI?

Comment: looks like not! it has `Add New Fields` button at the bottom of table schema page - but looks like it allows to add new field only to root

Answer (score 12):

You can also use the bigquery CLI tool which comes as part of the [gcloud command line tool](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud). I found this route easier because there is less information to add to the request. You don't need an access token or API key since your session is already established. You can find everything you need to know [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/managing-table-schemas) but the basics of it is:

`bq show \--schema \--format=prettyjson \YOUR_PROJECT_ID:YOUR_DATASET.YOUR_TABLE_NAME > schema_file.json` 
Then modify the schema file to add the new nested field.

Then run:
`bq update  YOUR_PROJECT_ID:YOUR_DATASET.YOUR_TABLE_NAME schema_file.json`

Comment: that's just great... cleaner, nicer and much quicker than the way above. Thanks for sharing