# BigQuery: How do I add a field to a REPEATED record?

Tags: google-bigquery

I've got a table in Google BigQuery that consists of a few fields, then a REPEATED record which may contain one or more objects. I want to create a new table with an extra field in the REPEATED data, and copy my original data into the new table, populating the new field with the output of GENERATE_UUID() so there is one unique identifier per REPEATED line of data.

I had a similar question at [How do I copy from one BigQuery Table to another when the target contains REPEATED fields?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60303028/how-do-i-copy-from-one-bigquery-table-to-another-when-the-target-contains-repeat) but I don't know how to adapt this to fit my current use case.

Here's my "new" Schema 1 (ie Schema 2 from the above link)

```
[
    {"name": "id", "type": "NUMERIC", "mode": "REQUIRED"},
    {"name": "name", "type": "STRING", "mode": "REQUIRED"},
    {"name": "created", "type": "TIMESTAMP", "mode": "REQUIRED"},
    {"name": "valid", "type": "BOOLEAN", "mode": "REQUIRED"},
    {"name": "parameters", "type": "RECORD", "mode": "REPEATED", "fields":
        [
            {"name": "parameter1", "type": "STRING", "mode": "REQUIRED"},
            {"name": "parameter2", "type": "FLOAT", "mode": "REQUIRED"},
            {"name": "parameter3", "type": "BOOLEAN", "mode": "REQUIRED"}
        ]
    }
]
```

and I'd like it to end up like this, Schema 2:

```
[
    {"name": "id", "type": "NUMERIC", "mode": "REQUIRED"},
    {"name": "name", "type": "STRING", "mode": "REQUIRED"},
    {"name": "created", "type": "TIMESTAMP", "mode": "REQUIRED"},
    {"name": "valid", "type": "BOOLEAN", "mode": "REQUIRED"},
    {"name": "parameters", "type": "RECORD", "mode": "REPEATED", "fields":
        [
            {"name": "uuid", "type": "STRING", "mode": "REQUIRED"},
            {"name": "parameter1", "type": "STRING", "mode": "REQUIRED"},
            {"name": "parameter2", "type": "FLOAT", "mode": "REQUIRED"},
            {"name": "parameter3", "type": "BOOLEAN", "mode": "REQUIRED"}
        ]
    }
]
```

So I've got my new table (Table 2) created with this Schema. I want to copy from Table 1, and I'm trying something like this:

```
insert into table2_with_uuid(id, name, created, valid, parameters)
select id, name, created, valid,
[(
GENERATE_UUID(), parameters.parameter1, parameters.parameter2, parameters.parameter3
)]
from table1_no_guid;
```

This gives me an error saying: 
`Cannot access field ceId on a value with type ARRAY<STRUCT<parameter1` (etc)

Does anyone have any suggestions as to how to proceed? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have followed the procedure in [Data Manipulation Language syntax](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/dml-syntax#tables_used_in_examples) on the official documentation.

Then, basically what you want is to [update repeated records](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/dml-syntax#update_repeated_records). I have followed all the examples, from the inserts to the updates up to the moment in which a second comment is added to the repeated record.

Then I applied the UNNEST query:

```
insert into `testing.followingDMLmod`  (product, quantity, supply_constrained, comments)
select product, quantity, supply_constrained,
[(
GENERATE_UUID(), com.created, com.comment
)]
from `testing.followingDML` , UNNEST(comments) com;
```

which of course works but does not provide the desired result.

As per the [official documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/nested-repeated#modifying_nested_and_repeated_columns) "BigQuery natively supports several schema changes such as adding a new nested field to a record or relaxing a nested field's mode." Then, perhaps the path is copying the table and afterwards adding the extra field.

That can be done following managing table schemas [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/managing-table-schemas#adding_a_nested_column_to_a_record). That is, either using the API and calling [tables.patch](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/tables/patch), which was discussed with more detail in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40033346/is-it-possible-to-add-a-new-field-to-an-existing-field-of-record-type-in-bigquer/40033682) other stack overflow post, or using a JSON file with the schema from the command line.

I have personally followed the second approach (JSON schema file) and worked perfectly for me. With more detail the steps I followed are (as found in [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/managing-table-schemas#adding_a_nested_column_to_a_record)):

- Use Copy table in the BigQuery UI to get a replica of your table without "id". My starting table is followingDML and the copy followingDMLmod.
- Copy the schema from your table into a JSON file (here called myschema.json) by running the following command in the Cloud Shell

```
bq show \
--schema \
--format=prettyjson \
testing.followingDMLmod > myschema.json
```

- Open the schema in a text editor. For example running

```
vim myschema.json
```

- Now modify the schema to add the new nested column to the end of the fields array. (If you have never used vim, a very simplified explanation would be "esc" returns you to normal mode, and while in normal mode clicking "i" allows you to write into the opened file,  ":w" saves the file and ":q" exits the file)
  I included the field "id":

```
{
  "mode": "NULLABLE",
  "name": "id",
  "type": "STRING"
}
```

- Now you need to update the schema by running

```
bq update testing.followingDMLmod myschema.json
```

Finally, back on the BigQuery UI I used the query

```
UPDATE `testing.followingDMLmod` 
SET comments = ARRAY(
    SELECT AS STRUCT * REPLACE(GENERATE_UUID() AS id)
    FROM UNNEST(comments)
  )
WHERE true
```

to populate the id field after creation. Following what is suggested in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44953369/update-nested-field-in-bigquery-table) stack overflow post. Now the end result is truly what it was expected!

Comment: Thanks for the massively detailed and considered reply, much appreciated. I follow your reasoning but I'm getting out of my depth with knowing what to do with tables.get and tables.patch API Explorers - I've not used these before nor any API Explorer, only the BigQuery web UI. Also when you say "the command line" for using a JSON file, can you expand on this? Do you mean the Cloud Shell link at the top right of the BigQuery UI? Sorry, new to this as well. Also what's in the JSON file?

Comment: No problem, I will include the steps I followed to do it from the command line in the Cloud Shell explicitly in my response.

Comment: I already included the steps, let me know if any of them is unclear. The Cloud Shell can be opened indeed using the link at the top right of the UI.

Comment: Thanks for the expanded answer! Massively familiar with vi btw :D I'll probably get around to testing this tomorrow, but thanks again for your help and expanding on the original answer.

Comment: Hi - thanks again for the detailed steps. If I understand correctly, this is what we're doing:

1. create identical copy of original table (no uuid) via BigQuery UI
2. at the commandline, extract the schema of the new table into some json
3. edit the json to add the new field "repeated" section
4. use `bq update` at the commandline to change the table's schema using the new json
5. run the UPDATE in the UI to move the uuid into the new field.  (continues)

Comment: My version fails at step 4 with the error message:
BigQuery error in update operation: Provided Schema does not match Table <project>:<dataset>.<table name>. Cannot add required fields to an existing schema. (Field: parameters.uuid)

(bonus question: how do I copy and paste from the Cloud Shell window? I just had to type that out by hand)

I'll keep persevering, but any insight into the above error would be welcome.
Thanks!

Tony

Comment: Got it! The new field needs to be NULLABLE. (https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/managing-table-schemas)

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to find an answer to this just before I posted - but thought it'd be useful to others to share the method. Here's the query that worked:

```sql
insert into table2_with_uuid(id, name, created, valid, parameters)
select id, name, created, valid,
[(
GENERATE_UUID(), params.parameter1, params.parameter2, params.parameter3
)]
from table1_no_guid, UNNEST(parameters) params;
```

Hope this is useful! Please feel free to add to my result or comment to continue the conversation.

Comment: that's obviously totally wrong! have you actually tested it?

Comment: Why is this solution not valid? I have tested it now and, although it reorders the rows, the id, name, etc, aligns with the right parameters and a UUID is generated into each one. Do you need the order to be kept?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm going to retest with another data set to be sure, but to answer your question, no, order is unimportant - although I am assuming partitioning and clustering will be preserved.

Comment: Please see my second "answer" posted above for continuing the discussion. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Everyone's correct. And incorrect. The unnest replaces the original data with one line per repeated record. Trying this query:

```
insert into dummydata_withuuid (id, name, created, valid, parameters)
select id, name, created, valid,
[(
GENERATE_UUID(), parameters.parameter1, parameters.parameter2, parameters.parameter3
)]
from dummydata_nouuid;
```

shows an error on the first parameters.parameter1, "Cannot access field parameter1 on a value with type ARRAY> at [5:29]"

However, remove the `insert into...` and modify as below line and the query is valid.

```
-- insert into dummydata_withuuid (id, name, created, valid, parameters)
select id, name, created, valid,
[(
GENERATE_UUID(), parameters
)]
from dummydata_nouuid;
```

And I can save the results as another table, which is a long way round of getting the answer I need. Is there something I need to modify in my `insert into...` line to make the query valid?

Comment: If I use this new query I obtain exactly the same as with the previous option with the downside that now a new table has to be created. Furthermore, the underlying schema is not the same (Won't be Schema2). I still do not understand why the previous query does not work properly for you. The UNNEST replaces the original data with one line per repeated record but after selecting them we put them back together into one Record type and we end up with Schema2. Can you share a dummy example where the past syntax (with UNNEST) fails? And what is your expected result? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, I agree with your statement about the UNNEST creating a single line per repeated record - what I'm not sure about though is "after selecting them we put them back together into one Record type". Say we've got a flat table as agreed - what's the ```select``` to get us back to a table with repeated records? Doesn't this need an intermediate table as well?

Comment: Hi Tony, I have been investigating and found a way to achieve what you want. I decided to post an answer with all the steps followed for clarity.

Comment: thanks! I'll test it out and post comments/questions below.